# How to make post request in react using axios

Tags: reactjs

**I tried to post data but it shows some error the code s attached to below**

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch
    const requestOptions = {
        method: POST,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    };
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/posts', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ postId: data.id }));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a POST request using axios in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960975/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-using-axios-in-react)

Comment: where is the screenshot? What error are you getting?

Comment: Also you are not using axios at all in your code snippet in the first place. You are using fetch api for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST method should be in double quotes.
try this code

```
componentDidMount() {
// Simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
};
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/posts', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ postId: data.id }));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

method:'POST' should be under double quotes

Answer (score 0):

if you want post this request that you right just make sure to use POST reserve key for method type inside of quotation,
but if you prefer to use axios library after install it with:

```
yarn install axios 
//or
npm install  axios
```

then import it into your file with

```
import axios from 'axios'
//or
const axios = require("axios")
```

then call post method of axios like below

```
axios.post('/user', { title: 'React POST Request Example' })
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
```